# I want to insert in a Oracle table with Java code and I get error on PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I want to insert a line in a table and I am doing a PreparedStatement and keep getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

This is the code:

What is wrong with this prepared statement ?

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ASIST_EMAIL (NUME, CNPCUI, LOCALITATEA, STRADA, NUMAR, BLOC, SCARA, APARTAMENT, JUDET, EMAIL, TEXTINTREBARE, CATEGCONTRIB, SECVENTA, DATA_EMAIL, CATEGSOLICIT, NUMEFISIER, ARONDARE, DOMFISCAL, SUBCATEGSOLICIT, TIPINTRARE, STARE, CODCATEG, CODSUBCATEG, HOST, AJCODSOC, AJCAEN, AJPERSCONTACT, DENREG) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       ps.setString(0, "test");
       ps.setInt(1, 999);
       ps.setString(2, "xxx");
       ps.setString(3, "xxx");
       ps.setString(4, "xxx");
       ps.setString(5, "xxx");
       ps.setString(6, "xxx");
       ps.setString(7, "xxx");
       ps.setString(8, "xxx");
       ps.setString(9, "xxx");
       ps.setString(10, "xxx");
       ps.setString(11, "xxx");
       ps.setInt(12, 999);
       ps.setTimestamp(13, new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
       ps.setString(14, "xxx");
       ps.setString(15, "xxx");
       ps.setString(16, "xxx");
       ps.setString(17, "xxx");
       ps.setString(18, "xxx");
       ps.setInt(19, 99);
       ps.setInt(20, 9);
       ps.setInt(21, 999);
       ps.setInt(22, 999);
       ps.setString(23, "xxx");
       ps.setInt(24, 9);
       ps.setInt(25, 9999);
       ps.setString(26, "xxx");
       ps.setString(27, "xxx");
       ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Step 1) Simplify as much as possible. ([mcve])

Comment: The first index of the ps.setXXX methods should be `1` .

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong index in setters, from [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)):

> parameterIndex - the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, ...

P.S. And also - such a big request is hard to read.